# Getting an error in "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" file. MVC @ajax.actionlink

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-ajax

[jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: a(...).live is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxGiw.png)

[Ajax Code
Trying to load data on Div element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zYeF.png)

Tried this, still not working

/*https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js")" type="text/javascript">
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript">*/

Comment: `.live()` was depreciated in jquery version 1.9

Comment: OK, which version of script file should i use? is it compulsory to use unobtrusive-ajax file for mvc ajax attributes?

Comment: You need to use a current version of `jquery.unobtrusive.ajax,js` (or better get rid of the awful `Ajax.ActionLink()` and use the `jquery.ajax()` methods)

Comment: can you please provide me the current version cdn. On everysite jquery.ajax.unobtrusive/3.2.4/jquery.ajax.unobtrusive.zip is available and i'm getting the same error.

Comment: I want to use actionlink and beginform methods